# Easy sufficient condition for a cubic to have a rational root?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, rational-numbers

Given a quadratic equation $f(x) =x^2 + bx +c$, with rational coefficients $b,c$ a sufficient condition for $f$ to have a rational root is for $\Delta = b^2 - 4c$ to be a square in $\mathbb{Q}$.

I was curious, does there exist a similarly simple sufficient condition one can check to see if the depressed cubic $g(x) = x^3+px+q$ with $p,q \in \mathbb{Q}$ has at least one rational root?

Comment: I do not think that there is an easy general criterion.

Comment: Well, the case of quadratics is necessary and sufficient. It is easy to give a sufficient condition for the cubic, like $q=0,$ but that isn't really what you want?

Comment: May not be exactly what you seek, but you may want to read up on the rational root theorem - it does give you an easy way to test a finite number of choices to conclude if a rational root exists or not.

Comment: There's https://www.jstor.org/stable/2691297 also, however wouldn't recommend that as an easy condition to test for existence of rational roots.

Comment: Certainly, if $\frac{q^2}4+\frac{p^3}{27}$ is a rational square, and $-\frac{q}2+\sqrt{\frac{q^2}4+\frac{p^3}{27}}$ is a perfect rational cube, then the equation has a rational root. That isn’t nearly a necessary condition - for one, it does not include any cases where all three roots are real, and only includes some cases where the equation has only one real root - but it is sufficient and handles a lot more cases than $q=0.$

Comment: A lot of cases boil down to “When is $a+b\sqrt{D}$ a perfect cube in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt D]?$” This is a hard problem in general. A necessary condition is $a^2-Db^2$ being a perfect cube, but that is far from sufficient.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Those are good points. I guess I'm more interested in a necessary condition. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for your response! Do you have time to explain the idea behind why bounded increments implies that positive recurrence is impossible?

Comment: @Michael I undeleted the post. Thanks for your help!